# I need to check if the 1st column of the last row in a file, matches with the 1st column of the next file & so on

Tags: unix

I have n number of files with sorted data, I need to check if the data in 1st column of the last row of File1 is matching with the data present in the 1st column of File2 and so on.

Once a match is found, the matched data from the 2nd file should be copied into the 1st file...the data from the 3rd file should be copied in the 2nd file when match is found between file2 and file3.

how can we solve this problem in unix?

For Example:

File1:

```
A1 apple
B1 banana
C1 Carrot
```

File2:

```
C1 Cabbage
C1 Cauliflower
D1 Doughnuts
E1 Egg
```

File3:

```
E1 Eggplant
F1 Fig
```

.... so on

**Output:**
File1

```
A1 apple
B1 banana
C1 Carrot
C1 Cabbage
C1 Cauliflower
```

File2:

```
D1 Doughnuts
E1 Egg
E1 Eggplant
```

File3:

```
F1 Fig
```

Comment: Do you want to end up with everything in order in file1? or with one less file than you started with?

Comment: If all the Column1 data matches between File2 and File3 then File3 should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following : each line must end with a line break and no empty lines at the end of files.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(tail -n 1 $1 | awk '{ print $1 }' ) == $(head -n 1 $2 | awk '{ print $1 }') ]
then
    cat $2 >> $1
    rm $2
else if [ $(head -n 1 $1 | awk '{ print $1 }') == $(tail -n 1 $2 
        | awk '{ print $1}') ]
    then
        cat  $1 >> $2
        rm $1
    fi
fi
```